# Question on overload non-member operator << in a linkedlist class in c++98

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++98

Can anyone help me with this question please? For background information, I have three classes, `Account.h` with `Account.cpp`, `Node.h` with `Node.cpp`, `LinkedList.h` with `Linkedlist.cpp`, and `demo.cpp` that contains `int main()`. All of the current functions are working except for printing out the linkedlist, which is the basis of my question.

The question specifically says:

> Implement a non-member overloaded `operator <<` function, that uses the `operator <<` from `Account`, to allow you to perform an operation like:
>
> `cout << MyLinkedList << endl;`

I copied specific parts of my code related to this question from `LinkedList.cpp` and `Account.cpp` because it will be too long if I paste it all here.

Code from `LinkedList.cpp` with overloaded `operator <<` function "not yet working" is as shown below: Please note `value_type` is typedef for `Account`.

```cpp
#include "LinkedList.h"
    
LinkedList::value_type LinkedList::getCurrent() const {
    if (current != NULL) {
        return current->getData();
    } else {
        return value_type();
    }
}
    
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list) { // not working, compile error!
    value_type current = getCurrent();
    while (current != NULL) {
        out << "(" << acc.getName() << "," << acc.balance() << ")" << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Code from `Account.cpp` is as shown below:

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Account& acc)
{
    out << "(" << acc.getName() << "," << acc.balance() << ")" << endl;
    return out;
}
```

These are the class declarations for my node.h file:

```cpp
#ifndef TEKAAI_NODE
#define TEKAAI_NODE

#include "Account.h"

class Node
{
    public:
        // members that are externally visible 
        
        // Below are Member functions
        
        // specifying value_type to Account using typedef
        typedef Account value_type;
        
        // Default constructor
        
        Node();     
        
        // Parameter Constructors
        
        Node(const value_type& initial_data, Node* initial_link);
        
        ~Node();    //destructor
        
        void setNext(Node* n);
        
        void setPrevious(Node* p);
        
        Node* getNext() const;
        
        Node* getPrevious() const;
        
        // the data getters and setters
        // Pre-condition: Current has been initialized 
        // Post-condition: set data
        void setData(const value_type& i);
        
        // Pre-condition: Data has been initialized
        // Post-condition: returns stored data
        value_type getData() const;
        
    private:
        value_type data;    //the data held by the node
        Node* next;         //a pointer to the next node
        Node* previous;     //a pointer to the previous node
};
#endif
```

These are the class declarations in my LinkedList.h file:

```cpp
#ifndef TEKAAI_LINKEDLIST_H
#define TEKAAI_LINKEDLIST_H

#include "Account.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

class LinkedList
{
    public:
        typedef Account value_type;
        // Members that are externally visible
        
        // These are Member functions
        
        // Constructors
            
        LinkedList();   
        
        // Destructor
        
        ~LinkedList();
        
        void addToHead(const value_type& account); 
        
        void addToTail(const value_type& account);
        
        void addCurrent(const value_type& account);
        
        value_type removeFromHead();
        
        value_type removeFromTail();
        
        value_type removeFromCurrent();
        
        // Pre-condition: LinkedList contains nodes
        // Post-condition: moves current to the head 
        void start();  

        // Pre-condition: LinkedList contains nodes
        // Post-condition: moves current to the tail
        void end();
        
        // Pre-condition: LinkedList contains nodes
        // Post-condition: moves current one node to the right
        void forward();  
        
        // Pre-condition: LinkedList contains nodes
        // Post-condition: moves current one node to the left
        void back(); 
        
        // Pre-condition: LinkedList contains nodes
        // Post-condition: returns the value of data account stored 
        // in current node
        value_type getCurrent() const;
        
        // Pre-condition: LinkedList is initialized, containing 
        // nodes
        // Post-condition: returns the length of the list
        int length();
    
    private:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        Node* current;
};  
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list);

#endif
```

As you can see in LinkedList class declarations above,I have to work with them to try and print out my linkedlist. I would like to hear your thoughts if it is possible to print my linkedlist using one of the above functions while also using the overloaded << operator from Account as the question specified.

Thanks.

PLUS NOTE: Just to let you know that I can get to print my linkedlist using the function 'Node* getHead() const;' which returns head in overloading the << operator, but I was just looking for help if it is possible to print linkedlist without using the getHead() function. I guess our lecturer was just messing with us, trying to make us lose our minds with his lab activity.

Comment: We don't want your entire code, but we want a [mcve]. Please read the link and make one.

Comment: *"Please note value_type is typedef for Account...."* It would be better if you just post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please also show the full text of the compiler output, what is the error? Without a [mre] or the compiler error we stand very little chance of helping you. At a guess `LinkedList` isn't copyable but you're passing it to the operator by value, make sure to use a reference

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , I have edited and posted all my class declarations for LinkedList class. Do you think it is possible to print out my linked list using one of the function above as well as using the overloaded >> operator from Account class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `operator<<`'s should be taking their 2nd parameters by const reference, not by value, eg:

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Account& acc)
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list)
```

Second, yes, it is possible to use the `Account` operator inside the `LinkedList` operator. You need something *equivalent* to the following (since you didn't provide full class declarations):

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list) {
    LinkedList::Node *cur = list.getFirst();
    while (cur != NULL) {
        out << cur->getData();
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return out;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: now that you have posted your `LinkedList` class declaration, I see that it does not offer anything like a `getFirst()` method. It has `start()` and `forward()` methods for iterating the list, but there is no method to indicate when the iteration has reached the end of the list.

So, you have a few options:

- add a new method to indicate that `getCurrent()` is safe to call:

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
    public:
        ...        
        bool hasCurrent() const;
        value_type getCurrent() const;        
        ...    
};
```

```
bool LinkedList::hasCurrent() const {
    return (current != NULL);
}

LinkedList::value_type LinkedList::getCurrent() const {
    return current->getData();
}
```

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, LinkedList& list) {
    list.start();
    while (list.hasCurrent()) {
        out << list.getCurrent();
        list.forward();
    }
    return out;
}
```

- change your `getCurrent()` method to return the `Account` object by *pointer* instead of by *value* so that it can return a `NULL` pointer when the iteration is at the end of the list:

```cpp
class Node
{
    public:
        ...        
        value_type& getData();
        ...
};
```

```cpp
LinkedList::value_type* LinkedList::getCurrent() {
    if (current != NULL) {
        return &(current->getData());
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, LinkedList& list) {
    Account *cur;
    list.start();
    while ((cur = list.getCurrent()) != NULL) {
        out << *cur;
        list.forward();
    }
    return out;
}
```

- make the `LinkedList` operator be a `friend` of the `LinkedList` class so it can access the private `head` member directly:

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
    public:
        ...
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list);
        ...

    private:
        Node* head;
        ... 
};  

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list);
```

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const LinkedList& list) {
    Node *cur = list.head;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        out << cur->getData();
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Remy Lebeau, thanks for the answer, For your information, I have edited my post to include my class declarations for LinkedList. Do you think it is possible to print out my linked list using one the functions in the class as well as using the << overloaded operator from Account class?

Comment: @TekaaiKaewaniti given the existing methods in the LinkedList class, no. I have updated my answer with alternative solutions.